# Use Fixed-Width Font in Teradata SQL Assistant Query Window?

Tags: sql, teradata

Really simple ask:

Teradata SQL Assistant's default font for code is variable-width. This is frustrating for formatting and readability reasons, among others. Is it possible to change the font to `Courier New` or something similar in the Query window? Google searches, perusing the options menus, and looking up the Teradata docs have yielded nothing...

Please help me code in monospaced font!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the first things I always do, +1 for *Courier New* :-)

You can also find this in the SQL Assistant's help, no need for Google.

*View* menu (or right click in the query window) -> *Set Font*

And then you can also use the editor in Column Mode:
*Alt+Drag Mouse* or *Shift+Alt+arrow key*

Comment: Just one menu item away, and I missed it! Thanks!

Comment: Consolas over Courier New for me. ;)